# What does an antenna range really mean?

Tags: antenna, range

When I hear that a base camp antenna has a range of 15-50 Miles does that mean it could reach a radio with a small antenna within that range, or that it would need to reach a radio with the same antenna?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With so many variables (antenna height, terrain, power, receiver sensitivity, frequency band, modulation mode, line loss, interference, time of day, other obstacles, (just to name a few)) such "ratings" are generally meaningless.  About all you can glean is that the manufacture claims that such an antenna might have more gain than one that claims a range of, say, 5-10 miles.  And even then, Your Mileage May Vary.

Comment: I see what you did there...